# How to add attachments to a post Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I look at the JSON data of a post which has several photos, I see that, this is done by using attachments/subattachments.

I want to post a data with several pictures and to do this, I want to take the advantage of attachments.

When I use "object_attachment" field for the post (to page feed), it creates only one attachment. Adding several "object_attachment" fields have no effect, only the first photo is used.

I want help on how to create attachment for a post and then add this attachment to the post.

Facebook says, attachments may be added to the posts to the post by "attachment_id" field.

Thanks to eveone who helps.